# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf', even after importing CommonModule

Tags: angular2-template

I know this have been posted a lot of time, but still not able to make it work.
Have 2 modules: AppModule and ModulebModule.

In AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In ModulebModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CompB01Component,
    CompB02Component,
    CompB03Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[
    CompB01Component,
    CompB02Component,
    CompB03Component,
  ]
})
export class ModulebModule { }
```

In template for CompB01Component:

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div>Component {{componentName}}</div>
    <div>
        <span *ngIf="text">Parameter name value is: {{text}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This compiles but still gets:

**NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.**

Answer (score 1):

Well... turns out you can navigate from a module to another, BUT app.module has to imports ModuleB for this error vanish. Why? Gonna read some more.